# How to fix ' ValidationError: users validation failed: name: Path `name` is required.' error in Mongo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm creating a new user and checking whether the user email previously exists or not. If not then it is creating a new user and saving it. What do I need to correct this validation error I am getting?

I have already tried by setting name as not required. But it still does not work.

This is my User model.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//Declaring User Model
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  avatar: {
    type: String
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);
```

This is the user route.

```
router.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then(user => {
    if (user) {
      return res.status(400).json({ email: "email already exists" });
    } else {
      const avatar = gravatar.url(req.body.email, {
        s: "200", //size
        r: "pg", //rating
        d: "mm" //default
      });
      const newUser = new User();
      const newUser = {
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        avatar,
        password: req.body.password
      };
      bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          newUser.password = hash;
          newUser
            .save()
            .then(user => res.json(user))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

I am expecting it to get stored. This is the error I am getting.

```
{ ValidationError: users validation failed: name: Path `name` is required.
    at ValidationError.inspect (G:\devconnector\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validation.js:59:24)
    at formatValue (internal/util/inspect.js:493:31)
    at inspect (internal/util/inspect.js:191:10)
    at Object.formatWithOptions (util.js:84:12)
    at Console.(anonymous function) (console.js:191:15)
    at Console.log (console.js:202:31)
    at newUser.save.then.catch.err (G:\devconnector\routes\api\users.js:39:35)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  errors:
   { name:
      { ValidatorError: Path `name` is required.
          at new ValidatorError (G:\devconnector\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validator.js:29:11)
          at validate (G:\devconnector\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1034:13)
          at G:\devconnector\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1088:11
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
          at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (G:\devconnector\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1043:14)
          at G:\devconnector\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2133:9
          at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
          message: 'Path `name` is required.',
          name: 'ValidatorError',
          properties: [Object],
          kind: 'required',
          path: 'name',
          value: undefined,
          reason: undefined,
          [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true } },
          _message: 'users validation failed',
          name: 'ValidationError' }
```

Comment: ```have already tried by setting name as not required. But it still does not work.``` please double check that the error message is the SAME when you set required false. It may throw an error relating to password after that looks like a similar error.

Comment: It is throwing same error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your code I can see that you are setting `newUser` as User() model object, then setting that to a plain javascript object. Which is wrong syntactically as well.

Basically you need make the model object with the values.

```
const newUser = new User({
   name: req.body.name,
   email: req.body.email,
   avatar,
   password: req.body.password
});
```

Comment: Good eye. Strange it isnt throwing error related to `const` redeclaration

Comment: Yeah, it is now working when I changed the model. But can you tell me more what was this about?

Comment: You were not making a model instance, you were just making a plain javascript object. A model is a class which has properties and methods like `.save()` when you were making `newUser = {..}` this was just an `Object` literal, not the Model class that had all those features.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thank you so much for your help. @AritraChakraborty

Answer (score 1):

the solution is so simple, now and in thew future avoid using additionnal parameters, you don't need them

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    username: String,
    password: String,
    googleId:   String,
    avatar_url: String,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar issue, got resolved by adding these lines in `app.js`:

```js
app.use(
    express.urlencoded({ extended: true })
);
    
app.use(express.json());
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your api post body contain the proper json keys and value pair for creating a new documents as per the mongoose model.

Answer (score 0):

The above issue will be cleared when you set the content-type to application or json in the post man then you can check it, will work normally with out producing error, I have faced the above error, I do the same it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to the above problem is simple, you just need to tweak some options in the postman tool. When you POST the JSON data from postman, make sure you select JSON from the dropdown as shown in the [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6eLW.png).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using the `create` method together with

```
{ upsert: true, new: true }
```

I deleted this line and the error was gone.

Answer (score -1):

```
  axios.post(`${API}/create-user`,data,{
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'token': localStorage.getItem('token')
          }
    })
    .then((res)=>{
        console.log(res)
        alert("User created successfully")
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err)
    })
```

changed multipart/formdata to application/json

Comment: Hi, there is an already accepted answer, that resolves the problem. You answer seems totally  out of context